# Hide Table Row After Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a table with rows of data from a mysql query.  Each row has a radio button and a submit button.  My goal is to hide the table row after the submit button has been clicked.

```
echo '<tbody>';
echo '<form id="hidrerow" action="http://myscript.php" method="post" target="_blank">';

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>Test Data1</td>';
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="productID" value=" ' . $productID . ' "></td>';
echo '<td><input name="mybutton" class="button" type="submit" id="hider" value="Submit">';
echo '</form></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('#hider').on('click', function(){
$('.table tbody td').find('input:radio:checked').closest('tr').hide();
})
```

When I click on a radio button and hit submit, the productID is getting posted to the myscript.php in a new window,  However the row does not hide after the submit button has been clicked?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: That is an invalid markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript code to:

```
$('#hider').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').hide();
});
```

This may not work because your mark-up is not valid. You cannot have a `<form />` in between like that.

Comment: Yeah you are right.  It doesn't work because the form is posting the data to another script.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Hexana What do you wanna do exactly? Can you create a fiddle of this? Move the `<form>` around the table then.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  What I wanted to do was hide the row after clicking the submit button.  I will try and move the form outside the table.  Thanks